# run multiple timer on single page with different timestamp jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have page where there are multiple timers.

Each match has different timers. They start when the match is being completed. When the user clicks on complete match button the match status is being changed to complete and the timers start based on start and end time received from the ajax request. So the problem I am facing here is when a match is being completed the first timer is running perfectly fine, but the 2nd, 3rd and so on should be running based on their own timers as their time slabs are different. But as of now all timers are the same as the first one.

I'm not sure what is wrong. Surprisingly, when I refresh the page it works fine as of the time is predefined using php but as soon as the timer runs on click of the button it conflicts until I refresh the page

1. Run multiple timers on single page
2. The countdown  only starts when user clicks button of relative row and the start time and end time is being received via ajax request as soon as request completes the timer starts based on start and end time received from the server

Problem :
Timer runs but it conflicts with other timers as it replaces with the countdown of the first row

```js
$(function(){
    function renderCountdown(setClass, setID) {
      // Logs 
      let days, hours, minutes, seconds; // variables for time units
      let count = 0;
      var getCountdown = function (c) {
          if (setClass == 'true') {
              var timeStart = $('#match-row-info-' + setID + ' input[name=timeStart]').val();
              var dateTime = $('#match-row-info-' + setID + ' input[name=matchTimeEnd]').val();
          }

          var dateStart = new Date(timeStart);
          var dateEnd = new Date(dateTime);
          let currentDate = dateStart.getTime();
          let targetDate = dateEnd.getTime(); // set the countdown date
          // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
          let secondsLeft = ((targetDate - currentDate) / 1000) - c;
          days = pad(Math.floor(secondsLeft / 86400));
          secondsLeft %= 86400;
          hours = pad(Math.floor(secondsLeft / 3600));
          secondsLeft %= 3600;
          minutes = pad(Math.floor(secondsLeft / 60));
          seconds = pad(Math.floor(secondsLeft % 60));
          // format countdown string + set tag value
          var clockData = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;

          if (setClass == 'true') {
              clockDiv  = '#match-row-info-' + setID + ' .match-timer';
              targetDiv = '#match-row-info-' + setID;
          } 

          if (hours <= '00' && minutes <= '00' && seconds <= '00') {
              clockData = '00:00:00';
              var clockDiv;
              var targetDiv;

              if (setClass == 'true') {
                  var matchStatus = $('#match-row-info-' + setID + ' input[name=matchStatus]').val();

                  if (matchStatus == 3 && seconds == '00') {
                      if(!$('#match-row-info-' + setID + ' .match-timer').hasClass('pause-clock')) {
                          //Additional function after time is compelted
                      }
                  }                
              } 
          }

          if ($(targetDiv + ' input[name=matchTimeEnd]').val() == '') {
              clockData = '00:00:00';
          }

          $(clockDiv).html(clockData);
      }

      function pad(n) {
          return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;
      }

      getCountdown();

      setInterval(function () {
            getCountdown(count++);
      }, 1000);
  }

if ($('.multi-match-timer').length > 0) {
  $('.multi-match-timer').each(function () {
    var setID = $(this).children('input[name=matchRowID]').val();
    renderCountdown('true', setID);
  });
}

function AddMinutesToDate(date, minutes) {
     return new Date(date.getTime() + minutes*60000);
}

function DateFormat(date){
var monthNames = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
  var days = date.getDate();
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var month = (date.getMonth()+1);
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var seconds = date.getSeconds();
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
  var strTime = monthNames[(month - 1)] + ' ' + days + ', ' + year + '/ '+hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
  return strTime;
}


  setTimeout(function () {
        var now = new Date();
        var next = AddMinutesToDate(now,5);
        $('#match-row-info-383 input[name=timeStart]').val(DateFormat(now));
        $('#match-row-info-383 input[name=matchTimeEnd]').val(DateFormat(next));
        $('#match-row-info-383 input[name=matchStatus]').val(3);
  }, 3000);
  
  setTimeout(function () {
        var now = new Date();
        var next = AddMinutesToDate(now,5);
        $('#match-row-info-385 input[name=timeStart]').val(DateFormat(now));
        $('#match-row-info-385 input[name=matchTimeEnd]').val(DateFormat(next));
        $('#match-row-info-385 input[name=matchStatus]').val(3);
  }, 6000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="match-row-info-383">
  <div class="match-timer-box multi-match-timer">
    <input type="hidden" name="timeStart" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="matchTimeEnd" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="matchRowID" value="383">
    <input type="hidden" name="matchStatus" value="2">
    <span class="match-timer ">00:00:00</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="match-row-info-384">
  <div class="match-timer-box multi-match-timer">
    <input type="hidden" name="timeStart" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="matchTimeEnd" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="matchRowID" value="384">
    <input type="hidden" name="matchStatus" value="2">
    <span class="match-timer ">00:00:00</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="match-row-info-385">
  <div class="match-timer-box multi-match-timer">
    <input type="hidden" name="timeStart" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="matchTimeEnd" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="matchRowID" value="385">
    <input type="hidden" name="matchStatus" value="2">
    <span class="match-timer ">00:00:00</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

you will notice all 3 timers have different time start and time end but still they are same there is some confliction in it

for example

match 1 ended
00:05:00 time should run here

match 2 pending
00:00:00 this match should not run any timer

match 3 ended
00:04:30 but this timer is being running as same for match 1

but when i refresh the page it works fine as the timer starts on click of button can anyone help me out

Comment: okay let me update question as code was so long so i used fiddle

Comment: how does the code know which `$('input[name=matchStatus]').val()` you want? you have more than one element with that name ... which one should be used?

Comment: I ran a loop to get the match status by this keyword is this wrong way to do so ?

Comment: `var matchStatus = $('input[name=matchStatus]').val();` will return the value of the first such element ... not sure what loop you're talking about

Comment: but what value do you expect in `var matchStatus = $('input[name=matchStatus]').val();` ... the actual line of code I was referring to

Comment: @JaromandaXI came into noticing that let me set that is this the reason why timer is being same but for the time start and time end I am giving different id

Comment: that's just one such error in your code - there may be more, there may not be - I stopped looking when I saw that

Comment: okay but i forgot to mentioned i made 2 scenarios the same timer runs on players profile where there is only 1 timer so that is why i made conditional statement let me update the code and remove that condition

Comment: Please clear up the description of the problem, so it's not one long run-on sentence.

Comment: @Barmar what is not clear in the description could you please specify as I PROVIDED ALL RELAVENT INFORMATION 

1) Run multiple timers on single page
2) timer only starts countdown when user clicks button and the time start and time end is being received via ajax request as soon as request completes the timer starts

Problem :
Timer runs but it conflicts with other timers replaces the countdown of the first countdown

Comment: I just find it difficult to read without sentence breaks, so I haven't really tried to understand what you're doing.

Comment: please see my updated question as I have mentioned the scenario and problem I am not sure if I made more clarification or not

Comment: @Barmar if you run the fiddle wait for couple of seconds and you will notice the issue you will see 1st timer and last timer have different time but the countdown will be same

Comment: your main issues are `var dateStart = new Date(timeStart);
          var dateEnd = new Date(dateTime);` result in invalid dates ... because `Mar 14, 2024/ 9:39:28` is not a format that `new Date` understands

Comment: I've tried to rewrite your text so it's proper English, with periods at the ends of sentences. I'm not sure what "When the user clicks on complete the timers start" means, though, I don't see anything called "complete".

Comment: thank you for that help sir this is when user clicks on a button to complete a match on that click of button ajax call is created to change match status in the db and create start and end time which I have added right now in set interval function to create same scenario

Comment: also `var dateStart = new Date(timeStart);` should be `var dateStart = new Date();` since you then use `dateStart.getTime();` and claim it is `currentDate`  - when in fact it isn't - that change and the one I mentioned above will fix the issue ... note `function DateFormat(date) { return date.getTime() }` will fix it

Comment: @JaromandaX it fixed it but unfortunately the time is skipping 1 seconds  59 57 55 53...https://jsfiddle.net/fLjpcwtg/4/

Comment: sorry, that should've been `return date.toISOString();` ... oh, yeah ... it does doesn't it

Comment: oh, that's because you DONT need to subtract `c`

Comment: @JaromandaX after removing c the timer is not running check the fiddle link I noticed one more thing after updating the time if I run  renderCountdown('true', setID); again as soon as the time is updated it works like a charm but the problem is it runs twice 

4:47:00
4:35:00 | 
4:46:00
4:34:00

Like this

Comment: @JaromandaX OMG it worked like a charm please put as answer your suggestion worked but please do explain why we do not have to defined start date as of we need to run 5 minutes from the time when the button was clicked as I want the timer to check 5 minutes from when the button was clicked if user refresh the page it should resume the time from when it was left make sense? this was the reason i predefined the start time

Comment: Look, to be honest, I won't be putting up an answer - I mean, I'd write this completely different and without jquery - like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/6cu7xopj/)

Comment: your concept works fine as well but i need the start time to be predefined is there a way to do that ? there is some reasons why I am doing that

Comment: Oh, right, so you'd have a start time and an end time, and only show a countdown between those two times ... makes sense

Comment: yes as soon as user clicks button if I run function at time of click of button it works fine but obviously after the same funs runs again there is no way to stop previously running function so if i ran the function after creating new ajax request it works fine but you knwo what happens when 2 or more functions start running at same time

Answer (score 0):

I figured out by my self after long research on every ajax call I do have to run the function again in order to start timer to run according to time assigned to each row there fore initially have to set start time as blank and check if the start time is empty do not run function for particular div so when ever ajax call is made run the function at that time but if there is any one who can also suggest me if this approach is wrong or is it correct. so this is what i did

```
if ($('.multi-match-timer').length > 0) {
  $('.multi-match-timer').each(function () {
      var setID = $(this).children('input[name=matchRowID]').val();

      /*only run the function if start time is predefined*/
      if($(this).children('input[name=timeStart]').val() != '') {
        renderCountdown('true', setID);
      }
  });
}
```

So when ever ajax call is made and it is the time to start the timer for a particular row run function at that time

```
$.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            renderCountdown('true', response.rowID);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having a bunch of anonymous global timers going on in the background, you can store the timer as a property of the element that is displaying that timer.

Here is an example that uses manual buttons, but you could trigger any of these events programmatically via an ajax callback as well.

Couple of other things to note about timers:

- 1000 doesn't mean 1 second exactly, it means anytime after 1000 milliseconds. Depending on what else the client is doing, you can get significantly longer delays than expected, so don't use intervals / timeouts for super time sensitive things.
- browsers can put the javascript event loop to sleep (say if a user is on mobile and the display shuts off). This will stop any interval / timeout. The workaround is to take timestamps, and then compute the difference to get the real time elapsed. It's a few extra steps that you may or may not need to consider.

```js
$('.match')
  .on('click', 'button[data-action="start"]', function() {
    let parent = $(this).parent()[0]; //use the element itself, not a jQuery object of it
    parent.time_elapsed ??= 0; //initialize values if necessary
    parent.timer ??= null; //can be undefined or int, we explicitly want null for not active
    
    if (parent.timer === null) {
      parent.timer = setInterval(function() {
        parent.time_elapsed++;
        $(parent).trigger('update_display');        
      }, 1000);
    }
  })
  .on('click', 'button[data-action="stop"], button[data-action="reset"]', function() {
    let parent = $(this).parent()[0];
    clearInterval(parent.timer);
    parent.timer = null; //clearInterval doesnt do this
    
    if (this.dataset.action === 'reset') {
      parent.time_elapsed = 0;
      $(parent).trigger('update_display');
    }
  })
  .on('update_display', function() {
    $(this).find('.display').text([
        this.time_elapsed / 3600,
        this.time_elapsed / 60,
        this.time_elapsed % 60
      ].map((t) => ('0' + Math.floor(t)).substr(-2)).join(':'));
  });
```

```css
.match{
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: 4rem repeat(3, 3rem);
  margin: 1rem 0;}
```

```html
<div id="38" class="match">
  <span class="display">00:00:00</span>
  <button data-action="start">start</button>
  <button data-action="stop">stop</button>
  <button data-action="reset">reset</button>
</div>
<div id="39" class="match">
  <span class="display">00:00:00</span>
  <button data-action="start">start</button>
  <button data-action="stop">stop</button>
  <button data-action="reset">reset</button>
</div>
<div id="40" class="match">
  <span class="display">00:00:00</span>
  <button data-action="start">start</button>
  <button data-action="stop">stop</button>
  <button data-action="reset">reset</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```